# Mod_rewrite: Include query string when redirecting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got a small problem with mod_rewrite. This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/moved.php?q=$1 [R=301,L]
```

This almost works, if I go to oldsite.com/apage.php, I get redirected to newsite.com/moved.php?q=apage.php.
However, if I go to oldsite.com/apage.php?var=15, I get redirected to newsite.com/moved.php?q=apage.php again.
How could I make oldsite.com/apage.php?var=15 redirect to newsite.com/moved.php?q=apage.php?var=15
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [*QSA* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to get the original requested query automatically appended to the new one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/moved.php?q=$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! It also changes the question mark to an exclamation mark, simply great!