# How to rewrite ssl and friendly URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, ssl, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have problem with following .htaccess rewrites.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\,]+)$ index.php?s=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

When I access site with http://ssl.droth-admin.ogicom.pl/kalkulator it redirects to https://ssl.droth-admin.ogicom.pl/kalkulator?s=kalkulator. When I access site with directly with https everything works well, ?s=kalkulator is not showing.

Test php:

```
<?php
//if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) AND $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
{
    echo ("SSL active");
    echo ("<br />");
    echo ("s=".$_GET['s']);
}
else
{
    echo ("SSL not active");
    echo ("<br />");
    echo ("s=".$_GET['s']);
}
?>
```

Is there any solution for the ?s=kalkulator to not show up after ssl redirection? I tried to switch redirects but it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod\_rewrite: Include query string when redirecting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836355/mod-rewrite-include-query-string-when-redirecting)

Comment: Linked question is not exactly what I need. Here after redirection ?s=kalkulator is appended, and I don't want it.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I read redirection and query string and searched for QSA, but it's not your problem. Maybe you need `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` for the first rule too? First rule forces `s` to be present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9,-]+)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```